# What exactly do I need to implement myself in Spring Boot to allow form-based authentication (using Spring Security and MVC)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm struggling to understand exactly what Spring Security/Spring Boot does under the hood and what is up to me to implement to get form-based authentication up and running (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html).

For reference, I'm building a web-app and am currently working on the backend, which is developed with Spring Boot. The data is stored in a nonrelational database. I haven't built the frontend yet and I use Postman to test my API's.

I followed this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=her_7pa0vrg) and this tutorial (https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security) to get a sense of how to use Spring Security, given the gargantuan size and dispersive nature of the official docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/index.html). Both tutorials use a deprecated class, but I chose to provisionally use it to make it easier to build a functional app - will change it later.

What I managed to understand is that Spring Security filters client requests with a series of methods (contained in a series of Filter classes) and what we do is basically *declare* how these filters should operate, rather than code them ourselves. This declaration is done through a Java configuration class, which establishes which resources are publically available, which are hidden behind an authentication wall and which need particular permissions, in addition to being authenticated, to be accessed. Furthermore, this configuration file is also where we declare what authentication methods we allow (with form-based authentication falling in this category).

The following is my (edited to ease understanding) configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
  private final AppUserDetailsService appUserService;
  
  @Autowired
  public SecurityConfiguration(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, AppUserDetailsService appUserService){
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.appUserService = appUserService;
  }
  
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
      // ... other configuration to protect resources
    .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login")
      .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
      .permitAll()
      .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
      .and()
    .httpBasic();
  }
  
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
  }
  
  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);
    return provider;
  }
}
```

where passwordEncoder and appUserService are two Components, which are declared in their own classes, and should respectively be used to encode user passwords and retrieve user authentication details (which go in a class implementing the interface UserDetails, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html and ) from the database.

Now, according to what I understand of the official docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html), the DaoAuthenticationProvider I build in the configuration class should take care of authentication matters. I do not need to define anything else in my code than what I mentioned above. Is that correct? This did not seem to work today, but I might have gotten something wrong in my Postman requests - thank you in advance!

EDIT (refer to my second batch of comments under @Toerktumlare 's answer):

My configuration file now looks like this (omitted UserDetailsService and PasswordEncrypter):

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("someUrl/{username}").access("@userSecurity.isSameUser(authentication, #username)")
                .antMatchers("/someOtherUrl/{username}/**").access("@userSecurity.isSameUser(authentication, #username)")
            )
            .formLogin((formLogin) ->
                formLogin.loginPage("/login")
                         .permitAll()                        
            )
            .logout((logout) ->
                logout.deleteCookies("remove")
                      .invalidateHttpSession(false)
                      .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

and I get this compile error: "The method access(AuthorizationManager) in the type AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl is not applicable for the arguments (String)", which I get. What I don't get is that the official docs do seem to use this .access() method with a String argument (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html#el-access-web-beans). I guess they're using a different .access() method, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get the whole thing to work. Please note I haven't tested this extensively yet, so I'll get back to this once I do and update this answer if necessary.

As to **the first part of my question** (which originally was the whole question: **"What do I need to implement myself?"**), the only things I needed to implement myself was the UserDetailsService and the PasswordEncoder interfaces. The former is the class that is responsible for retrieving user details (obviously actual access to the database can be delegated to another class, like Spring Repository's if using Spring Data). Spring Security does provide an implementation in case one has an in-memory database or a relational database, but this wasn't my case. It absolutely makes sense that users would have to write their own implementation, as Spring doesn't force any specific way of storing user credentials on you and therefore has no way of automatically knowing where to retrieve said credentials.

I also implemented a SecurityFilterChain bean (like @Toerktumlare did in his answer). When building your own application, you will most likely need to do this as well, but you might get form-based authentication to work even without declaring a SecurityFilterChain bean*. I haven't tested this, but it is definitely mentioned somewhere in the docs (will link this later if I find it and have the time).

Once your custom UserDetailsService and PasswordEncoder implementations are written and configured as a bean and thus made available for Spring to instantiate on its own, you're all done. Spring will automatically add them to its AuthenticationProvider (no need to implement this!) and use them for authentication.

Now, getting to the **second part of my question** (**"How do I get the [.access()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.0.0-M3/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#access(org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorizationManager)) method to work once I switch to http.authorizeHttpRequests()?"**), I eventually had to switch to implementing the [functional interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.0.0-M3/api/org/springframework/security/authorization/AuthorizationManager.html) requested by the .access method in this new setup. It now works as expected. I'm still baffled by the [snippet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html#el-access-web-beans) in the Spring docs where they use that method with a String argument (
N.B.: the link will redirect you to the section, I'm talking about the second snippet in that section (the one titled "Example 1. Refer to method").): either I'm missing something, or it's a mistake on their part. Will also investigate this further if I have the time.

*N.B.:
Technically, I think form-based authentication will work even if you do not define your own UserServiceDetails implementation: Spring will use one of its own implementations and generate a user and password for you. It will also print a message saying that for production you'll want to use your own UserDetailsService, so I just mention this for completeness.

Answer (score -4):

You are doing the same mistake as most people that start with spring security.

You don't read the [architecture](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html) chapter and the [Authentication Architecture](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html) chapter of the spring security documentation, and instead you google and follow an outdated tutorial.

You link to https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html which clearly shows no usage of `DaoAuthenticationProvider` but you still have implemented one.

So lets review your code:

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is [deprecated](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter), and should not be used so remove it. All you need to do now is to build a security configuration and return it to the context as a bean.

Then you have added both `FormLogin` and `httpBasic` these are two **completely different** ways of authenticating. I hope you are aware of it.

Basic is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.1/servlet/authentication/passwords/basic.html).
Form login is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.1/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html).

Lastly, if you provide a `UserDetailsService` and a `PasswordEncoder` but there is no need to configure your own `AuthenticationProvider`. Spring security will understand by itself that you want a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and build it for you as long as you provide them as `@Bean`s to the context.

So you can remove most of the rest of your code.

So this is what you final code could look like:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((formLogin) ->
                formLogin.loginPage("/login")
                         .permittAll();                            
            )
            .logout((logout) ->
                logout.deleteCookies("remove")
                      .invalidateHttpSession(false)
                      .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService() {
        return new AppUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new SCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

you honestly dont need more than that.

Comment: Hi and thanks! I'm not sure why you assume I haven't read those sections, when I link to the very same docs - I had in fact read them, it's just not easy to piece it all together. As to the page I directly linked, it does say that "The details of what AuthenticationManager looks like depend on how the user information is stored.", which is vague. Given that an Authentication Manager contains one or more AuthenticationProvider's (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-providermanager), I assumed it made sense to (1/2)

Comment: provide one as a Bean.
Yes, I'm aware form-based and basic auth are different, I was just following the tutorial in doing that. 

It would be super helpful if you could point me to where in the docs it clarifies what you explained to me (I could easily have missed it), otherwise thanks again, will try this when I can and then accept the answer I guess (2/2)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this still isn't working. Switching to `http.authorizeHttpRequests()` -(rathen than `http.authorizeRequests()`) means I can no longer provide a String argument to my .access() method, , which I previously did to provide a custom Spring EL expression like here (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html#el-access-web-beans). The snippet in the latter link does use it like that, though, which is kind of baffling. (1/3)

Comment: When I try to write something like `antMatchers("anUrl").access("aSpringElExpression")` I get this compile error: 

"The method access(AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext>) in the type AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizedUrl is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

which makes sense because `AuthorizeHttpRequestConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl` does not have an 'access' method accepting a String argument. (2/3)

Comment: I get that using `http.authorizeRequests()` meant I was using a different `access()` method, but then why is the snippet I mentioned above casually using a String argument? Am I missing something? (3/3)

(will add minimal code to my original post to illustrate what I'm trying to do)

Comment: Most your questions can be answered by actually reading the API. Why the code doesnt compile is because i wrote this by free hand without idea support. There was NO mention of the use of `access` and SpEL expressions in your original question. Stack overflow is not a forum, and i wont answer questions that keeps _moving_ as you update the question with more and more requirements.

Reading your comments tells me that what you are looking for is more of a mentor/senior developer that can answer your questions as you go. That is NOT what stack overflow is.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, you asked one question and i answered it.  If you are looking for rolling support i suggest you find discord servers etc than to ask on stack overflow. Also if you want a detailed answer you should ask a very detailed question. I answered after the question that was given. Dont blame the answer, blame the question. Good luck with your problem, im done here.

Comment: Very well, no need to vent your frustration here. Thanks for what help you managed to give me